Why do some requests fail with 'Invalid token' or 'Invalid Jsession ID' when passing session ID and token between HTTP requests in JMeter?
While passing the session ID and token from one HTTP request to subsequent requests in JMeter, some requests fail with messages such as "Invalid token" or "Invalid Jsession ID.
i have more than 100 API out of which 30-40 of them are failing rest are passing , these http request are in simple controller and my login request is separate out of the simple controller
in image you can see how i have set extracted cookie and token
**I started getting this issue when penetration testing related issues were fixed related to authentication and security **


